# When should I use ClearALLPools vs ClearPool?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I don't really understand the diff between them, When should I use ClearALLPools instead of ClearPool (or vice verse) ?

Is there any specific scenario to use one or the other ?

Comment: First off - what's made you think that you need to call *either* of them?

Comment: I got once a connection pooling issue (too many connections) from client apps, it turns out to be a bad handled connection object but that was something "fixable" since it was our app, for your comment I assume I should never use them.

Comment: Generally, no. The most common connection issue is if you're leaking connection objects. Fix the leak.

Comment: What's unclear? Use ClearPool if you want to clear a specific pool. ClearAll clears ... all pools!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connection pooling is massively beneficial, and something you should want to make use of  - it separates *actual* connections to the database from connection objects. You can create as many connection objects as you like, but the number of actual connections used are minimized.

However, there is a cost - **if** you don't manage your connection objects responsibly, then more actual connections than are (strictly) required will be opened up. At the extreme, this can lead to connections being refused because the pool has hit its limit.

The correct fix is to call neither `ClearPool` nor `ClearAllPools`. You should find the location(s) where you're leaking connection objects and fix them. In general, every connection object should *either* be cleaned up by way of a `using` statement, or, if it's meant to be kept open, it should be a member of a disposable object that closes the connection as part of its `Dispose` function.

---

As to the question, as asked - connection pools are based on the connection strings that are used. If you only use a single connection string for all connections, then the methods are equivalent. If you are using multiple connection strings then the difference becomes apparent, in a hopefully obvious way - that `ClearPool` only affects connections that are using the same connection string.

Comment: "same connection string" means the same string only, I meant diff applications can use the same string on the config file, is that a "same connection string" ? or diff assemblies will open a diff connection even if the string used in the connectionString is the same ?

Comment: @Allende - connection pools only exist within a single process. If two applications happen to use the same connection information, there's no co-ordination nor co-operation between the two.